# How can I fix duplicating menu items on the app menu plugin (xfce4-appmenu-plugin) on LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: xubuntu, libreoffice, appmenu

This seems to be happening only to LibreOffice Impress where its global menu duplicates. Even when the panel is in compressed view, its global menu would still duplicate on the app menu.

I'm using Xubuntu.

[image: Image of bug]